# VBA Search an array inside an array? (Check if all items of one array exists in another array)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, integer

IS it possible to look for an array of strings and/or integers inside an array of strings and/or integers? If so, then how?

To find a string in an array of strings I use code like:

```
If IsInArray(LowerFilmWidthArray, LowerFilmWidth) then
'Dos tuff
end if
```

And a function is:

```
Function IsInArray(arr As Variant, myVal As Variant) As Boolean

IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(myVal, arr, 0))
Debug.Print (IsInArray)

End Function
```

As a result example, imagine you have an array of integers (1-10) and You are looking if your array (1,5,6) are inside that previous array (all items of it) and then return True. In my case I am getting all my to look for values in columns from 3rd to last column with data, which would make up my array that I try to find ALL items of in another array and return true or false.

An actual example:

```
Dim LowerFilmWidthArray
LowerFilmWidthArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(320:420)"))

Dim LowerFilmWidth As Integer
LowerFilmWidth = Array(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(320, 400,400,620)
'I get theese from a range and they might as well be strings and an undefined number of defined by 3 to last column with data

if isinarray(LowerFilmWidthArray,LowerFilmWidth) then
msgbox("Great Success!")
end if
```

Result in this one would be false because of that last "620" which is not inside the LowerFilmWidthArray.

**EDITED:**

Still can't get this to work and my gut says that there's way too many unnecessary things in the answers when I simply need to take each item from an array and try to find it in another and get "TRUE" only if all items I was looking for are present in a big array.

I have converted my to look for array (smaller one) to get the values from a set range that will always be a row from 3 to lastcolumn.

```
Dim LowerFilmWidth
LowerFilmWidth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, LastColumn))
```

And I expect this part to make an array of all the values in cells in that range. Now I need to see if all those items / elements are present in:

```
Dim LowerFilmWidthArray
LowerFilmWidthArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(320:420)"))
```

So I use the suggested function:

```
Function arrElemInArray(arr As Variant, arrX As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean
   For i = LBound(arrX) To UBound(arrX)
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX(i)) Then
                boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
            If Not boolFound Then arrElemInArray = False: Exit Function
        Next j
   Next i
   arrElemInArray = True
   
  Debug.Print (arrElemInArray)
End Function
```

and engage it using

```
If arrElemInArray(LowerFilmWidthArray, LowerFilmWidth) Then
msgbox("Great success!")
End If
```

The solution has to work both with integers and strings. I still can't get it to work as expected. Often it returns "True" no matter what, but it seems that it only checks the first item in smaller array against the big array.

This code in the edit returns "subscript out of range" error on "CStr(arrX(i))".

But the values in the sheet are as in the image
[image]

The full subroutine looks like this:

```
Sub Testing()

Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim LowerFilmWidth
LowerFilmWidth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, LastColumn))

Dim LowerFilmWidthArray
LowerFilmWidthArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(320:420)"))

If arrElemInArray(LowerFilmWidthArray, LowerFilmWidth) Then
MsgBox ("Great success!")
End If

End Sub
```

**Workbook:**
[enter link description here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/512a5e2c6cafb0b29390aef7ede9c2bd20220127140905/819369)

Comment: What do you mean? I can't really loop through my columns using to look for value as a single string. That's what my question occurred

Comment: Would this be a practical example: 1.) `Data = Range("A3:A20").Value` and 2.) `Arr = Array(1, 5, 6)` i.e. return true if all elements of `Arr` are found in `Data`? Please share more detail because the efficiency of a solution will depend on it.

Comment: Ok Adding an example. The code I provide as an example is just an example and obviously doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't have a question here

Comment: @VBasic2008 it's the other way around I am looking for a range values to be inside a filter array (filter as in let it through if the whole range is inside the Arr)

Comment: What do you expect from `LowerFilmWidth = Array(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(320, 400,400,620)`? `LowerFilmWidth` being an `Integer`...

Comment: @FaneDuru Explained that at the bottom with an example. All these values must be looked for in that array which is 320-420. If any one is not inside it then it's a false match. And in the example it's a false match because of the "620" which is not inside 320-420. It's the same as looking for a singular string in an array, but here I need to look for multiple strings in an array at once (before moving on)

Comment: And I can't really loop through values and do the if statement for each as this what I provided is a single looking for in array if statement when in fact I have an if statement with about 50 values in 50 arrays connected with " and ". Where I need all 50 variables to be in their corresponding example arrays.

Comment: .Cells(320, 400,400,620) is not valid: you need an array, or a range that will be converted to an array, e.g. `.Range("A1:A100")` or `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 100))`? Which is it?

Comment: Your code line will only return an error. If you want what you (say) you need, you must create an array from a real range. Yours does not target any such a range. You maybe want using `ActiveSheet.Range(cells(320), cells(620))`. Then, if you need an array, which to be extracted from a `Range`, you should declare it as `Variant`. And it could simple be done as `LowerFilmWidth = ActiveSheet.Range(cells(320), cells(620)).Value`, but it would be a 2D array.

Comment: @fandure Those numbers ARE NOT cell rows nor columns. They are actual integers. The problem is in the code that actually compares an array of items to another array of items. (That exact part of the code). Maybe the problem is in how I dimension the variable taht previously I had as a single item.

Comment: Very interesting... This is happening only in your mind, no offence. Did you try the code? Does it return what you think it should? Without building correct and consistent arrays, you cannot search for anything, I'm afraid. So, forgetting about the example you tried showing, will the arrays in the jagged array be **only 1D arrays type**?

Comment: It's not what I am looking for as the numbers provided are items of an array and not cells nor row nor columns - just actual items. i.e. they could be written as "three hundred twenty" , ….." and so on

Comment: @FaneDuruI suppose so. If I understand what's a 1D array correctly

Comment: It looks we speak different languages... " So, forgetting about the example you tried showing, will the arrays in the jagged array be **only 1D arrays type**?"

Comment: @FaneDuru yes I suppose so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at the next example. Is this what you try accomplishing?

```
Sub testArrInArr()
  Dim arr(), arr1(), arr2(), arr3(), arr4()
  arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3): arr2 = Array(2, 3, 4)
  arr3 = Array(3, 6, 5, 4): arr4 = Array(4, 5, 6)
  
  arr = Array(arr1, arr2, arr3)
  Debug.Print arrIsInArray(arr, arr2)
End Sub

Function arrIsInArray(arr As Variant, arrX As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim i As Long, jArr As String
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Join(arr(i)) = Join(arrX) Then arrIsInArray = True: Exit Function
    Next i
End Function
```

**Edited**:

In order to test **each array element** if **exists in another array**, plese try the next way:

```
Sub tst2CheckArrElements()
  Dim arr, arr1, arr2
  arr = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ","): arr1 = Split("Sausage,Dog,Ship", ","): arr2 = Split("1,3,2", ",")
  
  Debug.Print arrElemInArray(arr, arr1)
  Debug.Print arrElemInArray(arr, arr2)
End Sub

Function arrElemInArray(arr As Variant, arrX As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean, mtch

   If Not IsArray(arrX) Then
         For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX) Then arrElemInArray = True: Exit For
        Next j
        Exit Function
   End If
   For i = LBound(arrX) To UBound(arrX, 2)
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If CStr(arr(j)) = CStr(arrX(1, i)) Then
                boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not boolFound Then arrElemInArray = False: Exit Function
        boolFound = False
   Next i
   arrElemInArray = True   
End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241478/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-search-an-array-inside-an-array-check-if).

Comment: @Faneduru Thanks this finally works with integers! But it doesn't work with strings where like I said many times that my bigger array is very rarely ``Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(320:420)"))`` more often it's a legit array of strings like ``Dim UpperFilmTypeArray
UpperFilmTypeArray = Array("Flexible")``. I've mentioned a lot that it must work with strings and or integers, be universally usable for anyone

Comment: Like the function I use for when I look for a single item in array - it works with both (integers and strings)

Comment: @Eduards Yes, you mentioned about using the solution for strings, too! But **it doesn't work with strings** DOES NOT SAY ANYTHING! Are you able to **accurately describe** what you try (**the involved strings, please**) and what **doesn't work** means? Does the code return an error? If yes, what error on which line? If not, what wrong is happening? I suppose you know that `StringA = stringA` is false. It is case sensitive! Please, show what strings do you try comparing!

Comment: @Faneduru Nothing is helpful in the way you pseudo explain the 'problem'... How do you imagine I can solve a problem without explaining it accurately? Should I test all possible strings? Please, share the 'problematic' workbook. It looks that we cannot understand well only speaking, in terms of what is happening and what is to be done...

Comment: Yup, friend! I know that it's case sensitive and there's no issue about that at all. It returns a type mismatch error during the function on line ``For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)`` in which both variables are "Type mismatch" .

Comment: complete code ``Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray
SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray = Array("Flexible")

Dim UpperFilmType
UpperFilmType = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Upper Film Type").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Upper Film Type").Row, LastColumn)).Value

If ArrayIsInArray(LowerFilmWidthArray, LowerFilmWidth) Then
MsgBox ("Great success!")
Else
MsgBox ("No bueno!")
End If``

Comment: So if in my shared workbook you change values to "Flexible" and other one to "Rigid" and the text in column "B" to "Upper Film Type" then subroutine to exactly what I posted in a comment above, you should see the issue

Comment: @Eduards If you call the function using `LowerFilmWidthArray`, but you never decalare and load it, the error only proves that you do not know very well what you are doing, no offence... I am trying to understand your code from the comment and I can only see `SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray = Array("Flexible")`. Is it something I missed?

Comment: @FaneDuru Well that's how i got it working previously, I might be missing something. In which case what is it? It's an array with a single item in it "Flexible" so all small array items must match that. Gonna share a modified workbook for your convenience

Comment: @Eduards Since we are not able to understand each other **only in words**, please share the workbook. I explained very clearly, on my tase, what is wrong: **You called the function with a not existing parameter**! Where in the code you show is `LowerFilmWidthArray` declaration and the way of lading it?

Comment: @FaneDuru workbook: https://easyupload.io/bumdzd

Comment: HAHAHA never mind, I guess I just forgot to change the arrays in that if function. That's my silly mistake

Comment: @Eduards There are to obvious problems, which means only not a logical way of using the code. 1. You should call it with the correct parameters. 2. Checking two parameters in an array of 1, it will return `False`, of course... Please **write `Option Explicit` on top of the module**! VBA will not let you making such silly mistakes, anymore... It will warn when a variable has not been declared.

Comment: Please, check the updated code [here](https://easyupload.io/rzujya). It is also **not case sensitive**, if you like it more in this variant...

Answer (score 1):

### Is Array In Array

**Personalized Study**

- Change the number format of the cells containing the values to general or to a numeric format to make it work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

    Const sHeader As String = "Parameters"
    Const sProperty As String = "Lower Film Width (mm)"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Machine Specification")

    ' Reference the last cell of the used range.
    Dim LastCell As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
        Debug.Print "UsedRange:        " & .Address(0, 0)
        Debug.Print "LastCell:         " & LastCell.Address(0, 0)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the header cell.
    Dim HeaderCell As Range
    Set HeaderCell = ws.Cells.Find(sHeader, LastCell, xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If HeaderCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' header not found
    Debug.Print "HeaderCell:       " & HeaderCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Calculate the first column number.
    Dim FirstColumn As Long: FirstColumn = HeaderCell.Column + 1
    Debug.Print "FirstColumn:      " & FirstColumn
    
    ' Calculate the last column number.
    Dim LastColumn As Long: LastColumn = _
        ws.Cells(HeaderCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastColumn < FirstColumn Then Exit Sub ' no data to the right of header
    Debug.Print "LastColumn:       " & LastColumn
    
    ' Reference the column range below the header cell
    ' to search for the property.
    Dim sDataColumnRange As Range ' below the header
    Set sDataColumnRange _
        = HeaderCell.Resize(LastCell.Row - HeaderCell.Row).Offset(1)
    Debug.Print "sDataColumnRange: " & sDataColumnRange.Address(0, 0); ""
    
    ' Reference the property cell.
    Dim sPropertyCell As Range
    With sDataColumnRange
        Set sPropertyCell _
            = .Find(sProperty, .Cells(.Rows.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
        If sPropertyCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' property not found
        Debug.Print "sPropertyCell:    " & sPropertyCell.Address(0, 0)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the property (values) row range (first to last column).
    Dim PropertyRowRange As Range
    Set PropertyRowRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(sPropertyCell.Row, FirstColumn), _
        ws.Cells(sPropertyCell.Row, LastColumn))
    Debug.Print "PropertyRowRange: " & PropertyRowRange.Address(0, 0)
    Debug.Print "PropertyRowRange Values" & vbLf & Join(Application.Transpose( _
        Application.Transpose(PropertyRowRange.Value)), ", ")
    
    ' Populate the property values array.
    Dim PropertyValuesArray As Variant
    PropertyValuesArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("Row(320:420)"))
    Debug.Print "PropertyValuesArray Values"
    Debug.Print Join(PropertyValuesArray, ", ")
    
    ' Return the result whether all values of the property row range
    ' are found in the property values array.
    If IsRowInArr(PropertyValuesArray, PropertyRowRange) Then
        MsgBox "All matching.", vbInformation
        Debug.Print "All matching."
    Else
        MsgBox "Not all matching.", vbCritical
        Debug.Print "Not all matching."
    End If

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a 1D array ('InArr')
'               contains all values in a row ('RowIndex')
'               of a range ('IsRange').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsRowInArr( _
    ByVal InArr As Variant, _
    ByVal IsRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal RowIndex As Long = 1) _
As Boolean
    Const ProcName As String = "IsRowInArr"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With IsRange.Rows(RowIndex)
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        If cCount = 1 Then
            IsRowInArr = IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Value, InArr, 0))
        Else
            Dim IsRow As Variant: IsRow = .Value
            IsRowInArr = Application.Count(Application.Match( _
                IsRow, InArr, 0)) = cCount
        End If
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Initial Answer**

- The function will return true if all the elements of an array (`IsArr`) are found in another array (`InArr`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub IsArrayInArrayTEST()
    
    Dim InArr As Variant: InArr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    
    Dim IsArr As Variant
    
    IsArr = Array(1)
    Debug.Print IsArrayInArray(IsArr, InArr) ' True
    
    IsArr = Array(1, 5, 11)
    Debug.Print IsArrayInArray(IsArr, InArr) ' False

End Sub

Function IsArrayInArray( _
    ByVal IsArr As Variant, _
    ByVal InArr As Variant) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim IsCount As Long: IsCount = UBound(IsArr) - LBound(IsArr) + 1
    Dim rArr As Variant: rArr = Application.Match(IsArr, InArr, 0)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = Application.Count(rArr)
    'Debug.Print rCount, IsCount
    If rCount = IsCount Then
        IsArrayInArray = True
    End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: Why is that function so complex now? That's what I started from when trying to look for just one item in an array, and it didn't work correctly in each occasion, so it got reduced to what I provided in OP

Comment: The complexity is to make it readable (understandable). You can always use the one-liner: `IsArrayInArray = Application.Count(Application.Match(IsArr, InArr, 0)) = UBound(IsArr) - LBound(IsArr) + 1`.

Comment: Solution doesn't work

Comment: Could you share an example when it doesn't work (if the arrays are 2D, the solutions can easily be rewritten)?

Comment: Absolutely! 
````
Dim LowerFilmWidthArray
LowerFilmWidthArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(320:420)"))

Dim LowerFilmWidth
LowerFilmWidth = Array("320", "420", "620")


If ArrayIsInArray(LowerFilmWidthArray, LowerFilmWidth) Then
End If
````
This is what I ran and it returned "true" even though you can see that it's all integers from 320-420 and it must be a false match because of that "620". I renamed the function btw

Comment: P.S. It returns false if I look for "320", "420" which both must be true as they are the first and last items in LowerFilmWidthArray. And remember that instead of numbers it could be strings of words

Comment: Two issues: 1.) You have switched the arrays, it should be e.g. `Debug.Print IsArrayInArray(LowerFilmWidth, LowerFilmWidthArray)`. 2.) You are writing the numbers as strings to `LowerFilmWidth` and comparing them to numbers in the other array: rather use `LowerFilmWidth = Array(320, 420, 620)`.

Comment: Yup! It seems to work now, but hey, if instead of prewritten numbers I have them taken from values in the sheet - i need to dim them as integers, right? And if so then how would I need to dim the LowerFilmWidth?

Comment: Although a certain logic would suggest the other way around, this will only work for a **one-column** range e.g. `LowerFilmWidth = Range("A1:A10").Value`. If you need it for a **one-row** range, e.g. `LowerFilmWidth = Range("A1:J1").Value` then you have to use `... = UBound(IsArr, 2) - LBound(IsArr, 2) + 1`.

Comment: When I use the range it doesn't work.
````
LowerFilmWidth = Array(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, LastColumn)).Value)
````
Which is supposed to take the values from the range column 3 to last column in the row taht has specified text in column 2